# The stackoverflow icon is misaligned

Tags: bug, icons

Something bugged me about that icon every time I saw it and I know why now.  The falling stack (excluding the one piece neatly placed in the box) is off to the left by 1 px.  Seems to be stretched slightly too.

Compared to the meta stackoverflow icon, you can clearly see the misalignment.  Observe the gif below.

[image]